# MySQL Join - Not unique table/alias error

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, unique

I am trying to join 2 tables but i got an error

> 'not unique table/alias: 'ct'

query is

```
select em.* ,ct.Cities_NAME
from Customer em,
     Cities ct inner join Cities ct on ct.Cities_ID = em.Customer_CITY 
where Customer_GROUP is NULL and Customer_ENABLED is not FALSE and Customer_TYPE != 'User'
```

where is the mistake and why?

Comment: The error message says it all. Use ct1 and ct2 for the two instances.

Comment: You have a typo `Cities ct inner join Cities ct` . `Cities ct` used twice

Comment: BTW, don't mix old implicit join and modern, explicit join. Use JOIN syntax everywhere.

Comment: You have an implicit join to cities then an explicit join to cities both with the same alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
select em.*, ct.Cities_NAME
from Customer em inner join
     Cities ct
     on ct.Cities_ID = em.Customer_CITY 
where em.Customer_GROUP is NULL and
      em.Customer_ENABLED and
      em.Customer_TYPE <> 'User';
```

For some reason, you have listed `ct` twice in the query.  You should also qualify all column references in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select em.* ,ct.Cities_NAME
 from Customer em , 
 Cities ct
 Where
 ct.Cities_ID = em.Customer_CITY -- it allows only matched id with city 
 and 
 Customer_GROUP is NULL  -- it accept when customer_group is null
 and 
 Customer_ENABLED not like '%FALSE%'  --it filter if customer enables is true
 and 
 Customer_TYPE not like '%User%'  -- it accepts customer type is not as user
```